# Can I implement potential field/depth first method for obstacle avoidance using boost graph?

Tags: c++, boost, robotics, boost-graph

I implemented an obstacle avoidance algorithm in Matlab which assigns every node in a graph a potential and tries to descend this potential (the goal of the pathplanning is in the global minimum). Now there might appear local minima, so the (global) planning needs a way to get out of these. I used the strategy to have a list of open nodes which are reachable from the already visited nodes. I visit the open node which has the smallest potential next.

I want to implement this in C++ and I am wondering if Boost Graph has such algorithms already. If not - is there any benefit from using this library if I have to write the algorithm myself and I will also have to create my own graph class because the graph is too big to be stored as adjacency list/edge list in memory.

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`boost::graph` provides a [list](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/graph/doc/table_of_contents.html) of Shortest Paths / Cost Minimization Algorithms.  You might be interested in the followings:  [Dijkstra Shortest path](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/graph/doc/dijkstra_shortest_paths.html),  [A*](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/graph/doc/astar_search.html).
The algorithms can be easily customized. If that doesn't exactly fit your needs, take a look at the [visitor concepts](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/graph/doc/visitor_concepts.html). It allows you to customize your algorithm at some predefined event point.

Finally [Distributed BGL](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/graph_parallel/doc/html/index.html) handles huge graph (potentially millions of nodes). It will work for you if your graph does not fit in memory.

You can find good overview of the Boost Graph Library [here](http://vw.indiana.edu/talks-spring06/doug.ppt).
And of course, do not hesitate to ask more specific question about BGL on stackoverflow.

Comment: In fact what I am going to do is similar to A*. However, I will explore the node next which has the smallest potential instead of having the smallest sum of "previous cost + estimated cost to goal". Is the A* implementation customizable enough to integrate this?

Comment: I awarded the bounty to you, thanks again for your answer. However, I'd still love to get a response to my comment above. Thanks, Philipp

Answer (score 1):

To my mind, `boost::graph` is really awesome for implementing new algorithms, because it provides various data holders, adaptors and commonly used stuff (which can obviously be used as parts of the newly constructed algorithms).

*Last ones are also customizable due to usage of visitors and other smart patterns.*

Actually, `boost::graph` may take some time to get used to, but in my opinion it's really worth it.